# Trying to scrape content of table using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

So I was trying to scrape the content of a table with the following code:

```
url = 'https://www.eleconomista.es/indices-mundiales/'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html5lib")
table=soup.find('table',{'class' : 'table tableFlex table-striped footable footable-1 breakpoint breakpoint-xs'})
print( table)
```

The output is

```
None
```

But I would like to print the table "Europa"

I would like to understand why I am not receiving the desired output and how to overcome this issue for future cases.

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add data then you can't find it with BeautifulSoup/lxml/requests/urllib/Scrapy which don't run JS. You would need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JS. OR: JS mostly reads data from server as JSON and if you find url used by JS to get data then you can use it to get data too. JSON can be easily converted to Python's list/dict and you don't have to search in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table has the classes "table tableFlex table-striped". So the following would work

```
soup.find('table',{'class' : 'table tableFlex table-striped'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing `None` because the page uses heavy Javascript and changes classes of the tags on the fly - you are seeing different classes in the browser than classes you get from `requests`. The string `'table tableFlex table-striped footable footable-1 breakpoint breakpoint-xs'` therefore captures nothing. You can try this script to capture some data (there are only `<tr>` tags inside the data-table, so selecting only them is ok):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.eleconomista.es/indices-mundiales/'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")

rows = []
for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    row = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
    if row:
        rows.append(row)

for row in rows:
    print(''.join('{: <20}'.format(d) for d in row))
```

Prints:

```
IBEX 35             9.170,50                                -0,60%              -55,20              9.225,70            19/07               
BEL 20              3.652,42                                +0,88%              +31,71              3.620,71            19/07               
DAX                 12.260,07                               +0,26%              +32,22              12.227,85           19/07               
CAC 40              5.552,34                                +0,03%              +1,79               5.550,55            19/07               
FTSE 100            7.508,70                                +0,21%              +15,61              7.493,09            19/07               
PSI 20              5.202,23                                -0,35%              -18,36              5.220,59            19/07               
EURO STOXX 50®      3.480,18                                -0,08%              -2,65               3.482,83            19/07               
ECO10               125,89                                  +0,03%              +0,04               125,85              19/07               
FTSE MIB INDEX      22.209,75                               +0,90%              +197,99             22.011,76           27/03               
DOW JONES           27.154,20                               -0,25%              -68,77              27.222,97           19/07               
NASDAQ 100          7.834,90                                -0,88%              -69,24              7.904,13            19/07               
S P 500             2.976,61                                -0,62%              -18,50              2.995,11            19/07               
NASDAQ COMPOSITE    8.146,49                                -0,74%              -60,75              8.207,24            19/07               
NIKKEI 225          21.456,10                               +1,95%              +410,38             21.045,72           19/07               
IPC MEXICO          41.606,54                               -0,03%              -11,57              42.551,54           19/07               
Merval              40.161,60                               -1,45%              -591,15             41.451,31           19/07               
IPSA                3.625,61                                +0,23%              +8,35               3.624,20            19/07               
LIMA INDICE GENERAL 20.845,29                               -0,36%              -74,36              20.839,30           19/07               
IGBC                13.762,88                               -0,21%              -29,61              13.792,49           4/06
```